# Extract username and message from string?

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to extract specific data from a log file such as date, username and the message itself.

This in an mock up of how the file looks like:

```
[2017-03-14 11:48:22] Steve T: Hi!
[2017-03-14 11:49:01] Oscar: Hi! :D How are u doin?
[2017-03-14 11:50:24] Steve T: Im doing great :P
```

I can extract the date with `preg_match("/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/", $string, $matches)`, but how do I fetch the username and the message with regex?

Comment: You can find position of first `:` but if your users have names with `:` - this approach is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working regex:

```
/^\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] ([\w\s]+): (.+)$/gm
```

And you can see a demo here: https://regexr.com/3ntg7

It translates to:

- `^` - start of line
- `\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\]` - the date inside square brackets (must be escaped)
- `([\w\s]+)` - the user name (**a mix of word (`\w`) and space (`\s`) characters**)

  - if the usernames can contain any character except colons, you can also use: `([^:]+)`
- `:` - colon after username (match is discarded)
- `(.+)` - match everything else
- `$` - end of line

And here's a PHP demo: https://3v4l.org/ovrt6

Caveats:

- be careful about the username format, right now I assumed it only contain word and space characters
- if messages can contain lines, then the regex need to be adjusted

Comment: Yeah, this is the best option.

Comment: Be aware that this will not cope well with usernames containing non-word-or-space characters, e.g. `Michael O'Hare` and `oscar-the-grouch`.

Comment: @salathe true, but he never mentioned the username format. I'll highlight that in the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that uses a formatted string.

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
[2017-03-14 11:48:22] Steve T: Hi!
[2017-03-14 11:49:01] Oscar: Hi! :D How are u doin?
[2017-03-14 11:50:24] Steve T: Im doing great :P
EOD;

$handle = fopen("data://text/plain,$str", 'r');
while ( false !== $line = fgets($handle) ) {
    print_r(sscanf($line, "[%[^]]] %[^:]: %[^\1]"));
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/Wq3Nb)